# Get content of special HTML tag by class name

Tags: php, html, xml

If I have an HTML page containing `<div class="post-inner">`, how can I get the content of this `div` with class name `post-inner` without any JavaScript? I just want the content of the `div` tag using PHP as fast as possible. I have tried this code but I don't know what to do after that:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.q8ping.com/49352.html');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$sxml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
print_r($sxml);
```

Comment: Maybe DOMXPath lib? `$domx = new DOMXPath($doc);
                    $values = $domx->evaluate("//div[contains(@class, 'post-inner')]");`

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi so you have getting the whole content of a certain website, and parse the one thing you need with JS? Do you consider this a better programming practice, to be honest - me neither

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XPath to accomplish that. Change your code to this:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.q8ping.com/49352.html');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$node = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'post-inner')]");
print_r($doc->saveHTML($node->item(0)));
```

You might want to check first though if an element was found.

Comment: @Fawaz, I updated my answer. You only had to access a property of the DOMElement to accomplish that.

Comment: thank you but it just text i need html tags like <h1> <p> i want to get every thing in side div  in html format i have try $node->item(0)-> innerHTML but it not work

Comment: i have this error DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in

Comment: What PHP version are you using? The manual states 1 argument can be given: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php

Comment: I want the result on basis of tag

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.q8ping.com/49352.html');
preg_match_all('/<div class=\"post-inner(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/div>/s',$page,$vv,PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($vv[0][0]);
exit;
```

Comment: @Fawaz are you use this?